# sub differential exercice

Tags: subgradient

Let $D$ be the unit disc in $\mathcal{R}^2$ and let $f : \mathcal{R}^2 → \mathcal{R}$ be the function $f(x) = d(x, D)$ =
the distance from $x$ to $D$. We are looking for the sub differential of $f$ at $\bar x$ that is we are looking for $\xi \in \mathcal{R}^2$ such that $\forall x \in \mathcal{R}^2$ : 
$$f(x) \geq f(\bar x)+\xi^T (x-\bar x)$$
First, I considered the case : $\|\bar x\| \leq 1$,
that is we are looking for $\xi \in \mathcal{R}^2$ such that $\forall x \in \mathcal{R}^2$ : 
$$f(x) \geq \xi^T (x-\bar x)$$
Since $f(\bar x)=0$ because $\|\bar x\| \leq 1$. In this case I find the sub diffential $\xi=0$.
$$ $$
But for the case $\|\bar x\| > 1$, I'm stuck and I don't know how to start...

Comment: $f$ is a radial version of a very simple function

Comment: $f$ such that : $$ f(x)=\| x \| -1~~ if~~ \| x \|  >1 ~~and ~~f(x) = 0 ~~otherwise $$ right ?

Comment: SylvainLhermite yes